# Volatile Keyword in function pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, volatile

I have doubts about the use of Volatile Keyword in function pointers.

I don't know if in this case, function pointers should be `volatile`

I use function pointers so that the same function, for example `sendCommand()` can use different uart's functions.

My code would be like this

```
//Function pointer
void (*volatile ptr_uart_putc) (unsigned char);

//Set function pointer
void uartConfig( void(*aPtr_uart_putc)(unsigned char) ){
  ptr_uart_putc = aPtr_uart_putc ;
}

void sendCommand(unsigned char aCommand){
  ptr_uart_putc(aCommand);
}
```

So in main I would do:

```
main(){
   uartConfig(uart0_putc);
   sendCommand('a');
   uartConfig(uart1_putc);
   sendCommand('b');
}
```

Comment: What you've shown so far doesn't require `volatile`.

Comment: I have doubts about the use of the `volatile` keyword in general.

Comment: `volatile` does not help for multithreading, and for async (interrupt/signal) code you'd have to ensure that function pointers are accessed atomically, since you certainly don't want torn accesses for them.